# Why is this user's profile picture served from a facebook server? (fbcdn.net)

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, facebook

While looking at a question, I noticed that the asker's profile photo didn't load. So, I opened the image in a new tab and noticed it was hosted at fbcdn.net.

Turns out my browser had blocked the image from loading on the SE because it was considered a tracker. (it loads fine when opened in its own tab)

I don't meant to single out this user in particular, but it's the only time I've seen something like this on the site.

Here's the [user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/121988/peter-kagey) ([archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190205013124/https://math.stackexchange.com/users/121988/peter-kagey)) and the [image](https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/39070124_10156761185585039_7334106104772689920_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=f299ee235c33dea865b0bd5bca457f02&oe=5D09F920) ([archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190407014811im_/https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/39070124_10156761185585039_7334106104772689920_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=f299ee235c33dea865b0bd5bca457f02&oe=5D09F920)).

- How did this image get added to this user's profile? (I can't seem to find the add-facebook-image button in my profile)
- Can I make my profile image one that's hosted on a remote server?
- Was I warned about SE sending data to third parties and just missed it while signing up?

Comment: From the [facebook tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/facebook/info): _“OpenID login provider - You can create and log into your account via your Facebook credentials”_. See other [questions tagged `facebook` and `profile-picture`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook+profile-picture).

Comment: So, you can make your profile photo your facebook profile photo, if and only if you use it to access stackexchange?

Comment: Kind of disturbing. Who says I want Facebook to track my movements across SE?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not load Facebook-based avatars directly from the Facebook CDN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164325/do-not-load-facebook-based-avatars-directly-from-the-facebook-cdn) (Personally I think [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303598/) is a closer duplicate, but it's marked as a duplicate of the first link anyways.)